# What is the conditional probability or probablity of classes of  languages?

Tags: formal-languages, lo.logic

What is the conditional probability or probability of classes of  languages?

Let $E,C,S,F,R $ be the class of computably enumerable languages,computable languagesl,context-sensitive anguages,context-free languages and regular languages respectively. $E$ is class of all computably enumerable languages and it's subset of $E$ is the Cantor space,take the uniform probability measure on the Cantor space,then what is  the  probability  or conditional probability $P(C),P(S),P(F),P(R),P(S|C),P(F|C),P(R|C),\cdots,P(R|F)$ ?suppose L is selected randomly under the fair-coin (Lebesgue-Cantor) measure on $2^{\omega}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The probability measure you're asking about is nonatomic, but your events of interest are countable.  Therefore the unconditional probability of each is zero, and the conditional probabilities are undefined.

Comment: Mr.Stein,thank you.yes,the the unconditional probability of each is zero.but the main question is the conditional probability.I have edit the post as appending "suppose L is selected randomly under the fair-coin (Lebesgue-Cantor) measure on $2^{\omega}$.

Comment: Probability conditioned on measure zero events is not well-defined.  I also don't understand your addition because you already mentioned the measure was the uniform measure on Cantor space.

Comment:  I just clarify what I have said in other way Since I do not know why you said the conditional probabilities are undefined or not well-defined. I understand now why you think the conditional probabilities are undefined.

Comment: @Mr.Stein.then how do you think about the conditional probability of $P(F|R)$?I think $P(F|R)=1$,although $P(R)=0$?

Comment: Sure, it would be natural enough to define $P(F\mid R) := 1$, but that does not make it clear that the other conditional probabilities make sense.

Comment: @Mr.Stein,then why do we not generalize the natural definition?And surely,the generalization is natural and well-defined.Thanks 

Similarly,let $R,Q,Z$ be set of real numbers,rational numbers and integers,then select a number from $R$,the conditional, probability$P(Q|Z)=1$,and $P(Z|Q)=0$,although $P(Z)=0$,$P(Q)=0$.I really do not understand why the question is not clear.

Comment: Informally speaking ,the second question is about the ratio of R/F,F/C,etc.And I do not know anyone has studied the question and gotten any meaningful result.I might have not sought for it ,if there were result about the question.Anyway,thank Mr.Stein.

Comment: So,we are expecting someone will solve the second question,It is probably very interesting.